# What are the hidden Dashy Crashy achievements?

Tags: achievements, dashy-crashy

I'm down to 2 cars left, the Hovercraft and the Tardis, in Dashy Crashy and I believe they may be related to the secret achievements I haven't gotten. How do I unlock the secret achievements in Dashy Crashy?

[image: Dashy Crashy Acheivements]

Answer (score -1):

**Test 1:** Hit two dozen cows
**Test 2:** Flatten an RC car

Answer (score -1):

**Test 3:** Hit seven cone streaks in a row.

Answer (score -3):

**Test 4:** Find a dinosaur egg to unlock a secret achievement
**Test 5:** Absorb 51 cars with the UFO to unlock another secret achievement